# exercise with lines algebra

Tags: analytic-geometry

This is an exercise I really can't solve by myself.

1) Let A(1,-1,0) a point on a line (e) line

2) Let (d) be a line perdicular to (e), given by a parametric equation.

How I can find the equation of (e)?

Comment: There is a typo in your title and I find it somewhat difficult to understand your question. You should not expect others to put more effort in their answer than you in your question.

Comment: I really try to be specific but english isn't my country language..so It's a bit difficult for me to explain all this mathematical things in a foreign language. what you didn't understand?

Comment: There are infinite lines that pass through point $\;A\;$, and there are infinite perpendicular lines to each such line, so your question makes no sense as it is. If you can write down your question in your mother tongue and you're lucky enough as to find someone here that can understand it...

Comment: the perdicular line (d) is specific..(the type is given). So I guess there is one only line which include A(1,-1,0) and is perdicular to the specific line (d)

Answer (score 0):

The parametric equations of a line in $\mathbb{R}$ are:

$$x=x_0+tu_1$$
$$y=y_0+tu_2$$
$$z=z_0+tu_3$$

Since A(1,-1,0) a point on the line (e) :

$$x=1+tu_1$$
$$y=-1+tu_2$$
$$z=tu_3$$

Since (d) is a line perdicular to (e) : ( $(d): (X,Y,Z)+t(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ )

$(u_1,u_2,u_3) \cdot (v_1,v_2,v_3)=0$

Comment: how to specify the parallel vector for the line (e) after that step?

Comment: You have to use the fact that (d) is a line perdicular to (e), the dot product of the lines' directions is zero..